# ffmpeg droping framerate on capture device

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, frame-rate

i have a hdmi capture device which seems to drop frames every now and then:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.8-0+enter code heredeb10u1+rpt1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avformat    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avdevice    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swscale     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  postproc    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0+deb10u1+rpt1 --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-vout-drm --enable-v4l2-request --enable-libudev --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mjpeg @ 0x1067210] Found EOI before any SOF, ignoring
[mjpeg @ 0x1067210] No JPEG data found in image
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 6996.350004, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'testfjfjfjf.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   32 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:00.51 bitrate=52814.3kbits/s speed=1.03x    
frame=   62 fps= 62 q=-1.0 size=    6400kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=51795.2kbits/s speed=1.01x    
frame=   93 fps= 61 q=-1.0 size=    9472kB time=00:00:01.53 bitrate=50639.8kbits/s speed=1.01x    
frame=  123 fps= 61 q=-1.0 size=   12800kB time=00:00:02.03 bitrate=51592.6kbits/s speed=1.01x    
frame=  153 fps= 61 q=-1.0 size=   15872kB time=00:00:02.53 bitrate=51342.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  184 fps= 61 q=-1.0 size=   18944kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=50905.7kbits/s speed=1.01x    
frame=  214 fps= 61 q=-1.0 size=   22784kB time=00:00:03.54 bitrate=52596.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  244 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   26880kB time=00:00:04.04 bitrate=54388.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  274 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   30720kB time=00:00:04.54 bitrate=55325.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  305 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   34816kB time=00:00:05.06 bitrate=56312.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  335 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   38656kB time=00:00:05.56 bitrate=56904.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  365 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   42496kB time=00:00:06.06 bitrate=57399.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  396 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   46848kB time=00:00:06.58 bitrate=58315.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  426 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   50944kB time=00:00:07.08 bitrate=58936.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  457 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   55296kB time=00:00:07.59 bitrate=59625.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  487 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   59904kB time=00:00:08.09 bitrate=60604.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  517 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   64768kB time=00:00:08.59 bitrate=61714.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  547 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   69376kB time=00:00:09.09 bitrate=62471.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  578 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   73984kB time=00:00:09.61 bitrate=63044.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  608 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   78848kB time=00:00:10.11 bitrate=63867.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  638 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   83456kB time=00:00:10.61 bitrate=64414.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  668 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   88064kB time=00:00:11.11 bitrate=64912.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  698 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   92672kB time=00:00:11.61 bitrate=65368.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  729 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=   97280kB time=00:00:12.12 bitrate=65699.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  759 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  101888kB time=00:00:12.62 bitrate=66087.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  789 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  105984kB time=00:00:13.12 bitrate=66125.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  819 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  109312kB time=00:00:13.63 bitrate=65699.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  849 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  112640kB time=00:00:14.13 bitrate=65303.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  880 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  115968kB time=00:00:14.64 bitrate=64864.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  910 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  119296kB time=00:00:15.14 bitrate=64522.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  940 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  122624kB time=00:00:15.64 bitrate=64202.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame=  971 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  125952kB time=00:00:16.16 bitrate=63823.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1001 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  130048kB time=00:00:16.66 bitrate=63922.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1031 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  134144kB time=00:00:17.16 bitrate=64029.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1061 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  138496kB time=00:00:17.66 bitrate=64235.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1092 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  143104kB time=00:00:18.18 bitrate=64473.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1122 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  147200kB time=00:00:18.68 bitrate=64544.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1153 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  151808kB time=00:00:19.19 bitrate=64775.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1183 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  155904kB time=00:00:19.69 bitrate=64834.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1213 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  160256kB time=00:00:20.19 bitrate=64994.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1243 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  164352kB time=00:00:20.69 bitrate=65045.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1274 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  168704kB time=00:00:21.21 bitrate=65143.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1304 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  172800kB time=00:00:21.71 bitrate=65188.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1334 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  176896kB time=00:00:22.21 bitrate=65231.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1364 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  180992kB time=00:00:22.71 bitrate=65272.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1395 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  185088kB time=00:00:23.23 bitrate=65267.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1425 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  189184kB time=00:00:23.73 bitrate=65305.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1455 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  193024kB time=00:00:24.23 bitrate=65256.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1486 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  197120kB time=00:00:24.74 bitrate=65251.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1514 fps= 59 q=-1.0 size=  200704kB time=00:00:25.21 bitrate=65204.3kbits/s speed=0.985x    
frame= 1568 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  207616kB time=00:00:26.11 bitrate=65125.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1598 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  211456kB time=00:00:26.61 bitrate=65083.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1628 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  215296kB time=00:00:27.11 bitrate=65043.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1658 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  219136kB time=00:00:27.61 bitrate=65004.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1688 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  222976kB time=00:00:28.11 bitrate=64967.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1718 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  226816kB time=00:00:28.61 bitrate=64931.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1749 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  230912kB time=00:00:29.13 bitrate=64932.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1779 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  234752kB time=00:00:29.63 bitrate=64898.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1809 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  237056kB time=00:00:30.13 bitrate=64447.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1839 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  239360kB time=00:00:30.63 bitrate=64011.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1869 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  241664kB time=00:00:31.13 bitrate=63590.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1900 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  243968kB time=00:00:31.64 bitrate=63149.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1930 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  246272kB time=00:00:32.14 bitrate=62754.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1961 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  248832kB time=00:00:32.66 bitrate=62404.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 1991 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  251136kB time=00:00:33.16 bitrate=62033.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2021 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  253440kB time=00:00:33.66 bitrate=61672.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2051 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  255744kB time=00:00:34.16 bitrate=61322.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2082 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  258816kB time=00:00:34.68 bitrate=61135.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2112 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  261376kB time=00:00:35.18 bitrate=60862.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2142 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  263680kB time=00:00:35.68 bitrate=60538.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2172 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  266240kB time=00:00:36.18 bitrate=60281.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2203 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  269056kB time=00:00:36.69 bitrate=60062.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2233 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  272896kB time=00:00:37.19 bitrate=60100.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2263 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  276480kB time=00:00:37.69 bitrate=60081.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2293 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  280064kB time=00:00:38.19 bitrate=60063.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2323 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  283648kB time=00:00:38.69 bitrate=60046.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2354 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  287488kB time=00:00:39.21 bitrate=60058.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2384 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  290816kB time=00:00:39.71 bitrate=59988.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2414 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  293376kB time=00:00:40.21 bitrate=59764.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2444 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  296192kB time=00:00:40.71 bitrate=59596.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2475 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  299008kB time=00:00:41.22 bitrate=59410.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2505 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  301312kB time=00:00:41.72 bitrate=59150.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2535 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  304128kB time=00:00:42.22 bitrate=58996.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2565 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  306688kB time=00:00:42.73 bitrate=58796.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2596 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  309504kB time=00:00:43.25 bitrate=58623.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2626 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  312576kB time=00:00:43.75 bitrate=58528.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2656 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  315648kB time=00:00:44.24 bitrate=58440.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2686 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  318720kB time=00:00:44.74 bitrate=58350.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2717 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  321792kB time=00:00:45.26 bitrate=58235.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2747 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  324864kB time=00:00:45.76 bitrate=58149.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2777 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  327936kB time=00:00:46.26 bitrate=58064.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2808 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  331008kB time=00:00:46.78 bitrate=57962.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2838 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  333824kB time=00:00:47.28 bitrate=57837.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2868 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  336640kB time=00:00:47.78 bitrate=57714.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2875 fps= 59 q=-1.0 size=  337408kB time=00:00:47.89 bitrate=57706.0kbits/s speed=0.989x    
frame= 2935 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  343296kB time=00:00:48.96 bitrate=57432.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2965 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  346112kB time=00:00:49.46 bitrate=57318.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 2968 fps= 59 q=-1.0 size=  346368kB time=00:00:49.51 bitrate=57304.8kbits/s speed=0.984x    
frame= 3027 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  351488kB time=00:00:50.83 bitrate=56646.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3058 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  354560kB time=00:00:51.34 bitrate=56566.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3088 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  357632kB time=00:00:51.84 bitrate=56506.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3118 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  360704kB time=00:00:52.34 bitrate=56447.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3149 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  363520kB time=00:00:52.86 bitrate=56333.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3179 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  366592kB time=00:00:53.36 bitrate=56276.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3209 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  369664kB time=00:00:53.86 bitrate=56221.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3239 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  372480kB time=00:00:54.36 bitrate=56128.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3270 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  374784kB time=00:00:54.87 bitrate=55944.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3300 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  377088kB time=00:00:55.37 bitrate=55780.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3331 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  379392kB time=00:00:55.89 bitrate=55599.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3361 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  381696kB time=00:00:56.39 bitrate=55440.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3392 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  384256kB time=00:00:56.91 bitrate=55306.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3422 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  386560kB time=00:00:57.41 bitrate=55153.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3452 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  388864kB time=00:00:57.91 bitrate=55003.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3482 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  391168kB time=00:00:58.41 bitrate=54855.5kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3512 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  393472kB time=00:00:58.91 bitrate=54710.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3543 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  395776kB time=00:00:59.43 bitrate=54552.7kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3556 fps= 59 q=-1.0 size=  396800kB time=00:00:59.64 bitrate=54495.9kbits/s speed=0.991x    
frame= 3616 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  401408kB time=00:01:00.71 bitrate=54158.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3646 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  403712kB time=00:01:01.21 bitrate=54024.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3677 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  406016kB time=00:01:01.73 bitrate=53878.8kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3707 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  408320kB time=00:01:02.23 bitrate=53749.2kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3738 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  410880kB time=00:01:02.74 bitrate=53641.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3768 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  413184kB time=00:01:03.24 bitrate=53515.6kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3799 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  415488kB time=00:01:03.76 bitrate=53378.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3829 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  417792kB time=00:01:04.26 bitrate=53256.9kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3859 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  420096kB time=00:01:04.76 bitrate=53137.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3890 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  422400kB time=00:01:05.28 bitrate=53006.0kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3920 fps= 60 q=-1.0 size=  424704kB time=00:01:05.78 bitrate=52890.1kbits/s speed=   1x    
frame= 3922 fps= 60 q=-1.0 Lsize=  425098kB time=00:01:05.81 bitrate=52913.4kbits/s speed=   1x    
video:425055kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.010058%
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

in my opinion this shouldn't be much of a problem but when i play back the file it has some pretty good "cuts" in there as if the video skips for half of a second. But on a framerate of 60 there must have been a framedrop of 30 frames to achieve this or am i wrong?

my record script:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -loglevel quiet -an -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -vcodec copy test.mp4
```

is there a way to "smoothen" the loss of frames as seen in the logfile?

or is there a way to determine what causes the framedrops? If it is ffmpeg, heavy CPU load or the capture device itself?

thanks a lot cheers Rudi

Comment: It may very well be just numerical error in fps reporting (assuming that's what you're going by). Try `ffmpeg -vf vfrdet -f null -` and see what it reports. As for "smoothening", you can post-transcode with `-r 60` output option to force constant framerate.

Comment: kesh - godfather of ffmpeg :D - i'm not sure if i got you right - if i add the -vf vfrdet -f null to my record script it says "Filtergraph 'vfrdet' was defined for video output stream 0:0 but codec copy was selected.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together."

Comment: ha, I left out the input options... `ffmpeg -i inputfile -vf vfrdet -f null -` (and lol no, I'm just an ojt assistant, reserve that status for guys like Gyan or Rotem)